# Multi-Select Unable to select option in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, accessibility

I've been playing around with an accessible version of a multi-select that has all the needed functionality for it to be usable with screen readers etc. I got the original version here: https://unfetteredthoughts.net/slides/technica11y/select.html

I made a few changes to it, mainly using Babel to convert it to ES5 so it works with IE. Now it works perfectly fine in Chrome however, in IE it displays properly but when you open the menu to select an option, if you click on one or use the arrow keys to access it, the menu closes without selecting anything and focuses back on the menu. It doesn't appear to be throwing any errors and I'm not sure why this is happening.

Here is the version I developed: https://jsfiddle.net/p0ay7cr5/

If you test it in Chrome, it works as expected but in IE if you click on an option, or press the down arrow to go through them, it fails.

I think the problem lies in the keydown function:

```
var onKeydown = function onKeydown(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  var key = event.key.replace('Arrow', '');
  var list = this;
  var options = Array.from(list.querySelectorAll('[role="option"]'));
  var index = options.indexOf(target);
  switch (key) {
    case 'Up':
      event.preventDefault();
      if (index > 0) {
        options[index -= 1].focus();
      }

      break;

    case 'Down':
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log("DownPressed");
      if (index !== options.length - 1) {
          console.log("In if for down");
          console.log(options[index + 1]);
          options[index += 1].focus();
          console.log("after focus");
          $('[id="directorsApprovalSearchForm:siteName"]').focus();
      }

      break;

    case ' ':
    case 'Spacebar':
      /* Selection made */
      console.log("SpacePressed");
      if (!target.hasAttribute('aria-disabled')) {
        event.preventDefault();
        onSelect(event);
      }

      break;

    case 'Home':
      event.preventDefault();
      options[0].focus();
      break;

    case 'End':
      event.preventDefault();
      options[options.length - 1].focus();
      break;

    case 'Esc':
    case 'Escape':
    case 'Tab':
      /* Hide list */
      event.preventDefault();
      hideList(list);
      break;

    default:
      /* Type ahead */
      // Do any of the items start with the character? Easy out
      if (options.some(function (option) {
        return findMatch(key, option);
      })) {
        // Find out if an item is already focused
        var focused = options.indexOf(document.activeElement);
        var next; // Nothing focused, start from the top

        if (focused === -1) {
          next = options.findIndex(function (option) {
            return findMatch(key, option);
          });
        } else {
          var start = focused += 1;
          var items = [].concat(options.slice(start), options.slice(0, start));
          next = options.indexOf(items.find(function (item) {
            return findMatch(key, item);
          }));
        } // Found something


        if (next !== -1) {
          options[next].focus();
        }
      }

      break;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually managed to figure out what the problem is. In IE, it was calling the onBlur method that focused off of the multi select and closed it. After commenting out these parts:

```
list.addEventListener('blur', onBlur);
```

and

```
list.removeEventListener('blur', onBlur);
```

The select worked perfectly in Chrome and IE.
Hope this helps anyone who stumbles upon this.

Answer (score 0):

After setting some debugger in your code, it seems that when select the options, it will not trigger the onSelect or onkeydown event, it just triggers the hideList function to hide the select options. After creating the new list items and append to the web page, we need to attach event to each of the select options.

From your description, you want to create a multi-select control, I suggest you could refer to the following sample, it will using some JQuery plugin, but it is very easy. Please refer to them:

1. using jQuery MultiSelect plugin.

   ```
   <script src="Scripts/multiselect/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <link href="Scripts/multiselect/jquery.multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <script src="Scripts/multiselect/jquery.multiselect.js"></script>
   <script>
       $(function () {
           $('#langOpt').multiselect({ columns: 1, placeholder: 'Select Languages', search: true });
       });
   </script>
   <select name="langOpt[]" multiple id="langOpt">
       <option value="C++">C++</option>
       <option value="C#">C#</option>
       <option value="Java">Java</option>
       <option value="Objective-C">Objective-C</option>
       <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
       <option value="Perl">Perl</option>
       <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
       <option value="Ruby on Rails">Ruby on Rails</option>
       <option value="Android">Android</option>
       <option value="iOS">iOS</option>
       <option value="HTML">HTML</option>
       <option value="XML">XML</option>
   </select>
   ```

   The screenshot as below:

   [image]
2. using bootstrap select plugin.

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
   <select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
       <option>Mustard</option>
       <option>Ketchup</option>
       <option>Relish</option>
   </select>
   ```

   The output like this:

   [image]